# How to see the test executions UI actually happening in azure pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My test case is: Opening an windows application and closing the same.
I am able to trigger automation in azure pipeline successfully. The test execution is happening successfully. But I am not able to see the UI of execution. 
Right now its kind of headless execution.
I want to see where the actual execution happens.
Where can I see the execution(want to see the UI)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which kind of UI test you were running. Azure DevOps support both Headless mode or visible UI mode.

> - **Headless mode.** In this mode, the browser runs as normal but without any UI components being visible. While this mode is obviously 
>     not useful for browsing the web, it is useful for running automated
>     tests in an unattended manner in a CI/CD pipeline. Chrome and Firefox 
>     browsers can be run in headless mode.
> - **Visible UI mode.** In this mode, the browser runs normally and the UI components are visible. When running tests in this mode on
>     Windows, [special configuration of the agents is required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/ui-testing-considerations?view=azure-devops&tabs=mstest#visible-ui-mode).

More details please take a look at official tutorial here-- [**UI testing considerations**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/ui-testing-considerations?view=azure-devops&tabs=mstest)

Comment: How to see the agent machine?

Comment: @AsitSahoo If you are using self-host agent, you could directly remote to that agent. If you are using host agent, we do not provide the way to remote connect it. You may use some method to  create a desktop shortcut to it,  finally download shortcuts in your build output. If you want to see the test in host agent  in real-time. Afraid, this is not available.